# Which version gradle will download if I do not specify any version in spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, gradle

I am working on spring boot application and did not specify any version in my build.gradle file,please see the below code.

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.postgresql:postgresql')
}
```

How gradle will automatically decide the version ?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies

Comment: That is defined int he `gradle.properties` file in the `gradle/wrapper` directory.

Answer (score 0):

If we talking about Gradle version. There are two options:

1. if in the project you have Gradle wrapper that you can specify the version in *gradle.properties* file in the *gradle/wrapper* directory and run specific Gradle version using the command `./gradlew build` [wrapper details](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)
2. in case if you don't have wrapper then you need specify some version in *Path* of your local machine. It can be checked via command `gradle --version` [instalation details](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html)

If we talking about dependencies we also have two options:

1. Gradle will download the latest version of the artifact from added repository [repository details](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html)
2. Use bom to specify set of artifacts versions [bom details](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/23/better-dependency-management-for-gradle)